# A generic error occurred in GDI+ in thу asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, bitmap

I have the following code:

```
 public override object ConvertToStorageType(object value)
        {
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap)value;

            string path = @"D:\image\img.jpg";
            image.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return path;
        }
```

on Save method I got error:**A generic error occurred in GDI+**

Where is problem?
PS. This asp.net app that generated XAF(devexpress) framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you dispose all objects of the method.

Comment: Use GC.Collect and dispose all graphics objects.

Comment: Actually, GC.Collect isn't needed. Just wrap every System.Drawing class instance in a using{} clause.

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure the directory exists
- Make sure you account running ASP.NET has correct permission to write to that folder
- Generally, you cannot save the bitmap to the file that is still in-use [especially if you obtain `value` from D:\image\img.jpg itself]

Answer (score 1):

This guy made a great post on his blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2009/02/28/solving-quot-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-quot-exception.aspx